# From Blender mesh to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, collider

I'm creating my terrain in Blender, as I feel more comfortable with it than using Unity's built-in tool. I have this mesh now, and I've implemented the LOD feature as well. The next problem to fix is the collider. I want to use the mesh collider for it. But I'm worried about performances. I split already my terrain in "chunks" each with its own LOD. I need to apply to each square a mesh collider.

What do you think about it? And also do you have any optimization advise?

On YouTube and on some Assets on the *AssetStore*, I can see a lot of modular terrains packages, and once I checked the mesh that they use, I can see that they are using mesh colliders everywhere.

Extra question: should the mesh be static?

Thank you guys for your time. To some, they might seem such stupid questions, but from someone who is starting now...Well, they still represent a big challenge.

Comment: MeshColliders might 1000x or so worse than basic sphere colliders in performance, but that doesn't mean they will crash your game. 1000x a very small number is still a reasonably small number. You can probably get away with static mesh colliders without performance issues. If you don't move or change your terrain during gameplay (which should be the case), it can be static. If you have performance issues, open the profiler (top bar > Window > Analysis > Profiler or press ctrl + 7) to check if it's the physics that's causing performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be a problem as long you create a mechanism to deactivate the unnecessary, and unused parts. Look also Ocullision culling and make all the terrains static.